# Bouncycastle issues Verifying a given ECC signature with given public key

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm using the C# Xamarin.iOS/Mono.Android port of Bouncycastle and I'm trying to verify an ECC signature with a secp256r1 curve with a given public key I have locally on iOS/Android device.

The signature generation is done on a remote device with a separate private key and sends it to me over a BLE link. When I receive it I attempt to verify it using the following code.

`myLocalPublicKey` and 'signatureFromDevice' are `byte[]` and set elsewhere

```
bool verify(byte[] signatureFromDevice)
{
   bool status = false;
   X9ECParameters curve = SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256r1");

  string caString = Utilities.ByteArrayToString(myLocalPublicKey).Replace(" ", "");
  Console.WriteLine("------ CA PUBLIC KEY " + Utilities.ByteArrayToString(myLocalPublicKey));

  ECDomainParameters curveSpec = new ECDomainParameters(curve.Curve, curve.G, curve.N, curve.H, curve.GetSeed());

  byte[] hex = Hex.Decode("04" + caString);
  Org.BouncyCastle.Math.EC.ECPoint q = curve.Curve.DecodePoint(hex);

  ECPublicKeyParameters publicKeyParameters = new ECPublicKeyParameters(q, curveSpec);

  var signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA-256withECDSA"); 
  signer.Init(false, publicKeyParameters); 
  signer.BlockUpdate (message, 0, message.Length);

  Console.WriteLine("------ SIGNATURE TO BE VERIFIED " +    Utilities.ByteArrayToString(signatureFromDevice));

 status = signer.VerifySignature(signatureFromDevice) // returns false
 return status;
}
```

> But when run this verifySignature() always returns false

But I've yet to find any API documentation and/or examples online of this scenario or what to check next since the ECPublicKeyParameters, ECPoint, and ECurve all seem to be instantiating normally. Anyone have any ideas from experience, etc? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but are you sure that you're using the right public key? A CA public key in general is not used to generate signatures except over specific parts of a certificate (the `TBSCertificate` part, to be precise). You are also parsing one `caString` and printing `myLocalPublicKey`... that doesn't seem correct. If possible also include the input in your question, that way we could possibly see if something is wrong.

Comment: PS naming something `ByteArrayToString` is horrible, just like `bin2ascii`. *Always* indicate the output format used (e.g. `toSpaceSeparatedHexadecimals`, the input is clear from the parameter) and if possible use library functions: one mistake in encoding / decoding and you'll always get `false`.